# My CPU claims it is 2.53 GHz but never reaches it. Why?

Tags: cpu, performance, overclocking, intel-core-i5

My CPU claims it is 2.53 GHz but never reaches it. I run CPU burner, and set c state limit to c0. All power savings are disabled and I set multiplier to 20T which is the only allowed turbo multiplier on throttlestop.

Maybe there could be another software for i5 which allows higher values? What is Intel trying to tell me by labeling this CPU as 2.53 GHz? so they they tested it with 2.53GHz setting and it doesn't freeze at 2.53 but they won't allow me to go that high? I'm guessing GPU is capable but the base clock is limited to 99.75 GHz by mainboard.

**EDIT: I installed ASUS power for gear and it increased my FSB to 140 MHz (pretty great) Now my CPU goes up to 2.94 GHz. Problem solved**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: you set the maximum multiplier to 21 and 21 * 100 = 2.1GHz

Comment: @magicandre1981 20T results in 21x . I don't see a higer mutiplier in any overclocking software.

Comment: uncheck the entry and let Windows manage the speed itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Core i5-460M has a default multiplier of 19.  When using ThrottleStop on a first gen Core i CPU, you need to adjust the Set Multiplier value to one more than the default multiplier to request maximum Intel Turbo Boost.

```
19 + 1 = 20 T
```

The maximum turbo boost multiplier for your CPU is 21 and that is exactly what ThrottleStop is showing in the FID column.

The problem is that Intel designed this CPU to use a base clock (BCLK) speed of 133.33 MHz.

```
19 x 133.33 MHz = 2533.27 Mhz (Frequency)
21 x 133.33 MHz = 2799.93 MHz (Turbo boost frequency)
```

http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_i5/Intel-Core%20i5%20Mobile%20I5-460M%20CP80617004116AI.html

Your CPU is working fine.  It is your motherboard that is not setting the correct BCLK value. You need to check to see if there is an updated bios for your motherboard.